# Transition Component on list elements

Tags: material-ui, react-transition-group

Is there a way to use any of the material-ui transition components on list elements so that they get animated on addition/deletion (but not mount)?
Just like here: https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition-group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `<Fade>` transition (or any other transition that material-ui has) and wrap your list-items with that transition.

```
<Fade in timeout={1500}>
  <ListItem key={value} role="listitem" button onClick={handleToggle(value)}>
    <ListItemIcon>
      <Checkbox
        checked={checked.indexOf(value) !== -1}
        tabIndex={-1}
        disableRipple
        inputProps={{ 'aria-labelledby': labelId }}
      />
    </ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemText id={labelId} primary={`List item ${value + 1}`} />
  </ListItem>
</Fade>
```

You can see a working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-fade-transition-list-item-e4i0c?file=/demo.js

The original code is from the example in the [material ui transfer list page](https://material-ui.com/components/transfer-list/#enhanced-transfer-list).

Comment: Thanks @Dekel! Sorry that I didn't say it explicitly but I want the transition ONLY on addition/deletion, i.e. not on initial render (just like it is in the transition-group example I've given. According to their docs the prop 'appear' is for that (default to true in mat-ui), but changing it only removes the transition altogether :(. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-fade-transition-list-item-35kz7?file=/demo.js

Comment: You can use the `useEffect` to change the timeout after the first load. example updated to show that.

Comment: @Tomek Thanks for accepting the answer. A vote-up will also be appreciated!

Comment: do you guys know how to animate removing an item?

Comment: @Mosijava Have you tried using [TransitionGroup](https://mui.com/material-ui/transitions/#transitiongroup) ?